# KVM is not available. This may mean the KVM package is not installed, or the KVM kernel modules are not loaded

Tags: kvm-switch

I'm planning to install a Virtual Machine in my system. However while creating a new virtual machine, the following warning message is displayed:

> KVM is not available. This may mean the KVM package is not installed,
>   or the KVM kernel modules are not loaded. Your virtual machines may
>   perform poorly.

What can I do to fix this? My specs are:

- RAM: 4GB
- Hard drive: 250GB
- Processor: Core 2 Duo
- OS: RHEL 7.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the kvm support on your host system. This support takes the form of a kernel module, either statically or dynamically built. 
Obviously it is not statically built in your case (it would have been auto-enabled).

Try to search an available dynamic kernel modules this way:

```
find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -iname '*kvm*.ko'
```

In my case I have two results being `kvm.ko` and `kvm-intel.ko` and in fact the first is a dependency for the second which is the module to use. Load it this way (with root privileges):

```
modprobe kvm-intel
```

And you should be ready to run your virtual machine.

Depending on your system (I have no RHEL around), you may need to install a package to get those .ko files.